# Unable to launch Safari 12 browser in Mac OSX using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, macos, selenium, safari, safaridriver

Recently I updated mac OS to "Mojave version 10.14" and "safari version 12.0" after that i am unable to lunch safari browser. Earlier it was running fine.
I am selenium "3.0.0"
here is my code:

Scenario 1:

```
case "safari":
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
driver = new SafariDriver(cap);
break;
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=safari, safari.options=org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariOptions@10eff, version=, platform=MAC}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:57 -0700'
System info: host: 'xxxx-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'xxxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
```

Scenario 2:

```
SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.setUseTechnologyPreview(true);
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver(options);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.quit();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: SafariDriver requires Safari 10 running on OSX El Capitan or greater.
Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:57 -0700'
System info: host: 'xxxx-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'xxxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.getExecutor(SafariDriver.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:62)
```

In both cases i am unable to run my test cases please someone help me. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=safari, safari.options=org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariOptions@10eff, version=, platform=MAC}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}] Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:57 -0700' System info: host: 'xxxx-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'xxxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
```

...implies that the **SafariDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Safari Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.0.0** of **2016-10-13 10:48:57 -0700** which is almost **2 years** older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u131* , *Selenium Client v3.0.0*

### Solution

- As an initial step you need to fulfil the following requirement ***...SafariDriver requires Safari 10 running on OSX El Capitan or greater...***
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *SafariDriver* to  current level.
- Upgrade *Safari Browser* to  current level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Browser/Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Thank you DebanjanB, It was incompatibility issue, some what i am bale to fix it and running tests successfully. But safari 12 now not accepting any third party extensions, i am unable add weddriver extension to safari 12 browser.

Comment: https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/safari-no-longer-supports-the-unsafe-extension-error.png